# Enable member functions of class templates using concepts

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-concepts, c++20

So I have a concept `Fooable`:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Fooable()
{
    return requires(...){ ... };
}
```

And I have a class template `Bar` that takes type `T` as template parameter and I want to enable a member function only if `T` is `Fooable`:

```
template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    template // ???
        requires Fooable<T>
    void MemFun();
};
```

Is it possible in C++17 with concepts TS or in C++2a?

Comment: Not the answer, but if you don't actually need disabled functions to not participate in overload resolution, you could simply use a `static_assert`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I do full template instantiation in my tests to see if all member functions are correct. Adding static_assert would break some of those.

Comment: with concept TS it is possible via `void MemFun() requires Fooable<T>() {}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In both the Concepts TS and C++20 designs, functions have an optional trailing *requires-clause*. So you don't need to make your member function a template to constrain it:

```
void MemFun() requires Fooable<T>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Constraints can go after the function in the trailing position:

```
template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    void MemFun() requires Fooable<T>;
};
```

[Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Gomn3Y)