# Outside class definition of member function enabled with concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432459/enable-member-functions-of-class-templates-using-concepts), I was trying to define a member function enabled by a concept outside the class definition:

```
template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = std::is_integral<T>::value; //could be anything...

template<typename T>
class F {
public:
    void foo() requires MyConcept<F>;
};

template<typename T>
void F<T>::foo() requires MyConcept<F<T>>
{
    //long implementation...
}
```

this piece of code works fine on GCC, but fails on MSVC and Clang.

Note that I need that the concept must be satisfied on `F<T>`, and not only `T` (my actual code is much more complex and uses variadic templates).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9oPa85qoq)

Clang says:

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'foo' does not match any declaration in 'F<T>'
void F<T>::foo() requires MyConcept<F<T>>
           ^~~

note: member declaration nearly matches
void foo() requires MyConcept<F>;
     ^
```

It works fine on Clang if I move the definition inside the class, but not on msvc:

```
template<typename T>
class F {
public:
    void foo() requires MyConcept<F> 
    {
        //long implementation...
    }
};
```

In any case, I would like to avoid having long implementations inside class definitions.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I define member function enabled with a concept outside the class correctly?

Comment: You are probably unlucky to run into various compiler bugs. For example, MSVC seems to like the external function if you have `MyConcept<F<T>>` in both places.

Comment: Thanks @BoP! So, is my first implementation theoretically correct?

Comment: Why have `<T>` at all?  You can use the injected class name there.

Comment: Looks like a clang bug to me.

Comment: @DavisHerring To work around a compiler bug, obviously.

Comment: Just opened a bug report to MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-error-C2244-when-defining-member-fu/10090884?entry=myfeedback&space=62&q=MSVC+error+C2244+when+defining+member+function+enabled+with+concept+outside+class

Comment: And I opened also a clang bug report here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56442

Comment: Just a small update: CLang solved this in version 16. 
MSVC still has this bug flagged as "under consideration" [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-error-C2244-when-defining-member-fu/10090884?entry=myfeedback&space=62&q=MSVC+error+C2244+when+defining+member+function+enabled+with+concept+outside+class). Please upvote if you also need it to be fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a compiler bug.

- It has been solved on Clang version 16;
- It is still not solved on Apple Clang;
- It seems to be solved on MSVC version 19.36.32532.0, although it is still "under consideration" [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-error-C2244-when-defining-member-fu/10090884?entry=myfeedback&space=62&q=MSVC+error+C2244+when+defining+member+function+enabled+with+concept+outside+class).

Note that, for MSVC 19.36.32532.0, in the function definition the `requires` clause must be the same of the declaration (`MyConcept<F>` and not `MyConcept<F<T>>`):

```
template<typename T>
void F<T>::foo() requires MyConcept<F>
{
    //long implementation...
}
```